# Service Area Polygon Geometry

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I  need to get a service area polygon (graphics) for inserting it into a query as geometry. 
This is a piece of code (a serviceAreaTask)

```
    serviceAreaTask.solve(params,function(solveResult){
      var polygonSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol("solid", 
      new SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new Color([232,104,80]), 2),
      new Color([232,104,80,0.25])
      );
     arrayUtils.forEach(solveResult.serviceAreaPolygons,function(serviceArea){
     serviceArea.setSymbol(polygonSymbol);
     map.graphics.add(serviceArea);
    });
```

According to API ServiceAreaSolveResult https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/serviceareasolveresult-amd.html

ServiceAreaPolygon is already a graphic, and I can use its geometry in my query, but I don´t know how I can get this geometry.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct! As mentined in document [`serviceAreaPolygons`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/serviceareasolveresult-amd.html#serviceareapolygons) are already in [`esri graphic`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#geometry) format.

Well, geometry is a property of the graphic. below is the way to access this.

**In your case-**

```
arrayUtils.forEach(solveResult.serviceAreaPolygons,function(serviceArea){
     serviceArea.setSymbol(polygonSymbol);
     var serviceAreaGeometry = serviceArea.geometry; // this is the geometry. you can use this geometry in your further query.
     map.graphics.add(serviceArea);
    });
```

**Hoping this will help you.**

Feel free to shoot your further queries.